# how to use sparkSession in dataframe write in pyspark using spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using **pyspark** and **spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.0.jar** with cassandra DB.
I am reading dataframe from one keyspace and writing to another different keyspace. This two keyspace have different username and password.

I created sparkSession using:

```
spark_session = None

def set_up_spark(sparkconf,config):
    """
    sets up spark configuration and create a session
    :return: None
    """
    try:
        logger.info("spark conf set up Started")
        global spark_session
        spark_conf = SparkConf()
        for key, val in sparkconf.items():
            spark_conf.set(key, val)
        spark_session = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=spark_conf).getOrCreate()
        logger.info("spark conf set up Completed")
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

I used this sparkSession to read data as dataframe as:

```
table_df = spark_session.read \
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
            .options(table=table_name, keyspace=keyspace_name) \
            .load()
```

I am able to read data using the above session. spark_session is attached to above query.

Now I need to create another session since the credentials for write table is different.
I have the write query as:

```
table_df.write \
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
            .options(table=table_name, keyspace=keyspace_name) \
            .mode("append") \
            .save()
```

I couldn't find how to attach a new sparkSession for the above write operation in cassandra.

How Do I attach a new SparkSession for write operation in pyspark with spark-cassandra-connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass that information as options to specific `read` or `write` operation, this includes things like: `spark.cassandra.connection.host`,

Please note, that you'll need to put these options into a dictionary, and pass this dictionary instead of passing directly, like described in [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md#passing-options-with-periods-to-the-dataframereader).

```py
read_options = { "table": "..", "keyspace": "..", 
  "spark.cassandra.connection.host": "IP1", 
  "spark.cassandra.auth.username": "username1", 
  "spark.cassandra.auth.password":"password1"}
table_df = spark_session.read \
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
            .options(**read_options) \
            .load()

write_options = { "table": "..", "keyspace": "..", 
  "spark.cassandra.connection.host": "IP2", 
  "spark.cassandra.auth.username": "username2", 
  "spark.cassandra.auth.password":"password1"}
table_df.write \
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
            .options(**write_options) \
            .mode("append") \
            .save()
```